# Change an array of ints to a series of strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve the following output from the following input:

```
Sample input:
3 4
2 1
4 5
-1

Sample output:
7
3
9
```

So far, I have my program doing all of the math and I'm getting it to terminate when the user puts in a negative number. My problem is that I'm having trouble getting it to print in the above format. A sample of my input/output is below:

```
9 9
8 8
9 -8
[18, 16]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class sums{
     public static void main(String[]args){
         int addition = 0;
         int previous = 0;
         ArrayList<String> sums = new ArrayList<String>();
         String sumsy = new String("");
         for (int i=0; i<=i;){
             Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
             previous = in.nextInt();
             if (previous<0){
                 break;
             }
             else {
                 addition = in.nextInt();
                 if (addition<0) {
                     break;
                 }
                 else {
                     addition += previous;
                     sums.add(addition+"");
                 }
             }
         } System.out.println(sums);
     }
}
```

I believe the answer lies in somehow using a delimiter ("/n") *somewhere*, and getting my array of ints to print out just as strings.

I'm sorry, these small things elude me completely. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!
-Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` object, and its `println` methods are overloaded for a variety of different types.

In this case, because sums is an `ArrayList`, you're calling [`println(Object x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29), which works by calling `String.valueOf(x)` on the passed object (which in turn calls `x.toString()` if `x` does not equal `null`), and printing the resulting `String`.

Essentially, when you pass something other than a `String` or a primitive to `println`, you're delegating the details of how it gets printed to the class of the object. In this case, since `ArrayList` is a library class, you have no control over this.

To make it work the way you want, you need to iterate over the values in sums, something like:

```
for (String someSum : sums) {
    System.out.println(someSum);
}
```

If you're not familiar with that loop syntax, see the second half of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: One small thing, unrelated to your question specifically: it's a bad idea the give your variables and your classes the same names, because it makes reading your code a lot more confusing. For this reason, it's conventional to always start class names with a capital letter and always start other names with a lower-case letter. That way, you'll never accidentally name them the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not familiar with the syntax, so I'm reading the page you sent now. Also, I renamed the variables one uppercase/one lowercase - I hadn't thought of that, but it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (String sum : sums) System.out.println(sum)
```

use this instead of

```
System.out.println(sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

sums is an list of strings, not a string, so printing it isn't going to give you what you want. You have two options, you could do
 `for(String i : sums){ System.out.println(i); }`

or you could make sums a stringbuilder and do `sums.append(addition)` and then  `System.out.println(sums.toString())`

Comment: Just use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums))` instead of doing it manually

Comment: that won't get the newline she needed. (you still probably have the easiest way to do it, but `code sums.add(addition+"");` needs to be replaced with `code sums.add(addition+"\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use an ArrayList? IMO, this makes it much more complicated than necessary. From your example input, it appears that you simply want to sum each pair of numbers. This doesn't seem to require an array. You could just add the two numbers together and immediately print out the result.